# How to automatically move nodes and links at the same time in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying the [force-directed example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph) in d3.js(v7).
In this sample, when I drag a node, the links and other nodes move in tandem.
I want all nodes to move randomly at all times, and I want other links and nodes to move in tandem with them, just as if I were dragging them.
The code is below. The json file is the same as the sample. When I run this code, the nodes move, but the links don't follow the movement and remain stationary.

```
function ForceGraph({
    nodes, // an iterable of node objects (typically [{id}, …])
    links, // an iterable of link objects (typically [{source, target}, …])
  }, {
    nodeId = d => d.id, // given d in nodes, returns a unique identifier (string)
    nodeGroup, // given d in nodes, returns an (ordinal) value for color
    nodeGroups, // an array of ordinal values representing the node groups
    nodeStrength,
    linkSource = ({source}) => source, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
    linkTarget = ({target}) => target, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
    linkStrokeWidth = 10, // given d in links, returns a stroke width in pixels
    linkStrength = 0.55,
    colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of color strings, for the node groups
    width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
    height = 400, // outer height, in pixels
    invalidation // when this promise resolves, stop the simulation
  } = {}) {
    // Compute values.
    const N = d3.map(nodes, nodeId).map(intern);
    const LS = d3.map(links, linkSource).map(intern);
    const LT = d3.map(links, linkTarget).map(intern);
  
    if (nodeTitle === undefined) nodeTitle = (_, i) => N[i];
    const T = nodeTitle == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeTitle);
    const G = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeGroup).map(intern);
    const W = typeof linkStrokeWidth !== "function" ? null : d3.map(links, linkStrokeWidth);
  
    // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
    nodes = d3.map(nodes, (_, i) => ({id: N[i], type: NODETYPES[i], tag: parsed_NODETAGS[i], texts: X[i]}));
    links = d3.map(links, (_, i) => ({source: LS[i], target: LT[i]}));
  
    // Compute default domains.
    if (G && nodeGroups === undefined) nodeGroups = d3.sort(G);
  
    // Construct the scales.
    const color = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.scaleOrdinal(nodeGroups, colors);
  
    // Construct the forces.
    const forceLink = d3.forceLink(links).id(({index: i}) => N[i]);
    if (nodeStrength !== undefined) forceNode.strength(nodeStrength);
    if (linkStrength !== undefined) forceLink.strength(linkStrength);
  
    const zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 40])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
  
    const svg = d3.create("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2.5, width, height])
        .on("click", reset)
        .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");
    
    svg.call(zoom);
    const g = svg.append("g");
  
    const link = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .join("line");
  
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", forceLink)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center",  d3.forceCenter())
      .on("tick", ticked);
    
    const node = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .style("opacity", 1.0)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .join("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .call(drag(simulation));
  
    if (W) link.attr("stroke-width", ({index: i}) => W[i]);
    if (G) node.attr("fill", ({index: i}) => color(G[i]));

    function random(){
        node
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
          .attr("cx", function(d){
            return d.x + Math.random()*80 - 40;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d){
            return d.y + Math.random()*80 - 40;
          });
      }
    setInterval(random, 800);
    if (invalidation != null) invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());
  
    function intern(value) {
      return value !== null && typeof value === "object" ? value.valueOf() : value;
    }
  
    function ticked() {
      node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  
      link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
    }

    function drag(simulation) {    
      function dragstarted(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
      }
      function dragged(event) {
        event.subject.fx = event.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.y;
      }
      function dragended(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        event.subject.fx = null;
        event.subject.fy = null;
      }
      return d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
    }

    function zoomed({transform}) {
      g.attr("transform", transform);
    }
  
    return Object.assign(svg.node(), {});
}
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you could create a [mre] of your code, preferably in a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) with some sample/dummy data that helps us understand the problem. That way, we can more easily answer your question and you'll be more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: Just adding more code is not the same as a [mre], you need to make it runnable and debuggable, and remove all unnecessary features (like drag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `random()`, you don't change the underlying data, you only change how it is represented. Each `circle` holds a reference to an element in the `nodes` array, but you set `cx` and `cy` within `random()`, you don't update the underlying data `d.x` and `d.y`. And even then, the values the circle has for `cx` and `cy` are not reactive. That is, they are not re-evaluated when `d.x` or `d.y` changes.

So I would split your code. Have a function `random()` that is called every 800ms and shuffles the nodes around a bit by changing `d.x` and `d.y`. And then the `simulation` is in charge of actually drawing the circles and the links - the way it already seems to be doing.

```js
const size = 500;

const nodes = [{
    id: 'A',
    x: 150,
    y: 150
  },
  {
    id: 'B',
    x: 250,
    y: 250
  },
  {
    id: 'C',
    x: 350,
    y: 350
  }
];
const links = [{
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[1]
  },
  {
    source: nodes[0],
    target: nodes[2]
  }
];

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', size)
  .attr('height', size)
  .attr('border', 'solid 1px red')
const g = svg.append('g');

const node = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("r", 5);

const link = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .join("line");

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).strength(2))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(2))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(size / 2, size / 2).strength(0.05))
  .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
  node
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  link
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
}

function random() {
  simulation.stop();
  nodes.forEach(d => {
    d.x += Math.random() * 80 - 40;
    d.y += Math.random() * 80 - 40;
  });

  node
    .transition(1000)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  link
    .transition(1000)
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y)
    .on('end', () => { simulation.restart(); });
}
setInterval(random, 2000);
```

```css
.links>line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```